# htaccess, redirect from old page to new page (php and post variable)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My question is, how to redirect correctly by htaccess my old page to my new page ?

I tried that but without success :

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php?page=wallrank-top10-1&requete=keyword&searchkeyword=crac$ http://serveurs.top-minecraft.fr/index.php?keyword=crack$1 [R=302,L]
```

In my htaccess this one work perfectly so I don't understand :

```
RewriteRule ^portail\.html$ http://www.top-minecraft.fr/portal.php [L]
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: You cannot use query arguments in a RewriteRule. They are not part of the url you test against. This is clearly stated in the documentation. Please read it. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want when user call http://serveurs.top-minecraft.fr/index.php?keyword=crack they go to http://serveurs.top-minecraft.fr/index.php?page=wallrank-top10-1&requete=keyword&searchkeyword=crac

Comment: Or redirect http://serveurs.top-minecraft.fr/index.php?keyword=crack to http://serveurs.top-minecraft.fr/motclef/crac.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the moment, without find any solution based into htaccess, I use an php if condition in my index page =>

```
<?php

$requeteurl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($requeteurl == 'http://serveurs.top-minecraft.fr/index.php?keyword=crack') {
Header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
Header("Location: http://serveurs.top-minecraft.fr/index.php?page=wallrank-top10-1&requete=keyword&searchkeyword=crac");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will be enough to redirect with params

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://serveurs.top-minecraft.fr/index.php [R=302,L]
```